# Add "figure" behind the number in LOF

Tags: table-of-contents

Using `\listoffigures` command, how can I add "figure" behind the figure number in the list?

For example:

```
Figure 1 foo bar......5
Figure 2 foo bar......6
```

And not just

```
1 foo bar......5
2 foo bar......6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question. But the suggestions depend on the documentclass.

Only from the comment to an other answer I know that you are using package `tocstyle` with option `tocfullflate`. For all suggestions using other packages you have to deactivate package `tocstyle` for the List of Figures (`lof`):

```
\usepackage[tocfullflat]{tocstyle}
\deactivatetocstyle[lof]% deactivate tocstyle for lof
```

With a **KOMA-Script** class (loads package `tocbasic`)  you can simple use option `listof=entryprefix`. Example:

```
\documentclass[listof=entryprefix]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[tocfullflat]{tocstyle}
\deactivatetocstyle[lof]% deactivate tocstyle for lof
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{1cm}
  \caption{A caption}%
\end{figure}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

With a **standard class** you could load package `tocbasic`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[tocfullflat]{tocstyle}
\deactivatetocstyle[lof]% deactivate tocstyle for lof

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  indent=0pt,
  entrynumberformat=\useprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{figure}
\newcommand*\useprefix[2]
  {#1~#2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{1cm}
  \caption{A caption}%
\end{figure}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or you can use package `tocloft`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[tocfullflat]{tocstyle}
\deactivatetocstyle[lof]% deactivate tocstyle for lof

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename~}
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{5em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{1cm}
  \caption{A caption}%
\end{figure}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]